# Master and develop branch never synced even follow git-flow process in bitbucket

Tags: git, bitbucket, git-flow

I am following git-flow branching model with my repo hosted on Bitbucket Cloud.

- contributions are done to `feature` branches (branched out from `develop`) which are merged into `develop` branch via PRs
- when a release is needed:

  1. create a `release` branch from latest `develop`;
  2. merge `master` into `release`; **(I will have to perform this step as explained later)**
  3. increase version number;
  4. merge `release` into `master` via PR.
- when a hotfix is needed:

  1. create a `hotfix` branch from latest `master`;
  2. increase patch version number
  3. merge `hotfix` into `master` via PR.
- when a hotfix is done:

  1. create a `bugfix` branch from latest `master`;
  2. resolve a lot of conflicts;
  3. merge `bugfix` back into `develop` via PR.

I have been following the above procedures strictly. However, the `master` and `develop` are never synced, even right after a release, the indicator on Bitbucket Cloud branches page tells me the `master` branch is "99 commits behind develop" and "11 commits ahead of develop".

Every time when doing a release, Bitbucket Cloud always tells me that the two branches are not in-sync (even I have not done any changes to the `master` branch after the previous release), hence I have to perform step 2 of the release procedures above. This step becomes harder and harder as it keeps adding back files that has been removed from `develop` (and should have been removed from `master` as well) during the merge process.

I'm not sure what I have done wrong. Can anyone suggest?

Comment: Are all merges true merges? Just checking....

Comment: @matt I'm not sure if there is a fake merge? I rarely use git cli, I have been using Soucetree GUI and recently switch to Intellij's git GUI. All I have been doing when attempting a merge is: checkout a branch, select another branch and click "merge into current" in the GUI and then resolve conflicts using the GUI's interactive merge tool.

Comment: But you can’t do that for a PR because you’re not on your computer. You’re on the remote’s web interface. And it might offer a fake merge. For example, squash and merge, offered by github, is not a merge. Let me put it another way: is there a two-parent merge commit every time you use the word “merge” in the story?

Comment: @matt You are right. For all the PRs, I always use "squash and merge" to the target branch, as it gives a cleaner commit history for the target branch... Emmm, so I think using the "squash and merge" is the problem here?

Comment: Yes, exactly. It doesn't give you a "cleaner" commit history; it gives you _no_ commit history. The branches remain separate. Hence, as you say, you never get synced.

Comment: @matt Thanks Matt. I think I know how to solve this. For all the feature -> develop PRs I will still perform "squash and merge" as feature branches are transient; but for develop -> master PRs I will do true merge after which develop and master will become synced. Am I right?

Comment: Yes. Squash and merge is very nice for a kind of history-less forward iteration, where, say, `develop` appears to grow magically step by step by intelligent purposeful iterations. If you work on a feature branch and squash merge onto `develop` and force delete the feature branch, it just looks like `develop` progressed ingeniously, and no one the wiser. But for true long-lived parallel branches, such as `develop` and `master`, if "merge `release` into `master` via PR" means "squash merge", `release` and `master` are just growing _independently_, which is a disaster.

Comment: Having said that, I am personally fond of true merges everywhere. I _like_ the train-track siding architecture of little feature branches that emerge from develop and rejoin it later. To me, _that_ is git flow.

Comment: @matt thanks I used your info to compose an answer below. Thank you!

Comment: Oh, one more thing (sorry, I don't mean to nag): don't do a PR for the `develop`-to-`master` merge. That train has left the station. These commits have been approved; that is what `develop` is for. Just merge.

Comment: @matt Yes, I have never done a direct `develop`-to-`master` merge as the repo is configured to have no direct write access to both branches. It's always been PRs for `release`-to-`master` or `hotfix`-to-`master`.

Comment: Ah, yes, it makes sense to set up guards on your branches.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @matt pointed out in the comments above, the root cause of `develop` and `master` branches never in-sync is because I have always been using "squash and merge" in the Bitbucket PR.

I just performed a release (`develop` -> `release` -> `master`) by merging the release PR into `master` using "explicit merge" (non fast-forward), and now `develop` and `master` branches are in-sync.

For the different merge policies, ie. **explicit merge (non fast-forward)** vs **implicit merge (fast-forward)** vs **squash and merge**, one can refer to this article [Pull Request Merge Strategies: The Great Debate](https://blog.developer.atlassian.com/pull-request-merge-strategies-the-great-debate/) for a high level discussion of the differences. I found the GIFs very helpful.